# How to determine the time complexity of the nested loop?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I know that first loop is of O(n) and since second is nested loop it is going to be O(n * something). I know that nested loop will be iterating n time and decrementing each time. But how to decide it's time complexity?

```
int a = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = N; j > i; j--) {
        a = a + i + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick way to think about it: There are `N` executions of the inner loop. The inner loop, on average, runs `N/2` times, because `i` is below `N/2` and above `N/2` equally. So the total number of steps is proportional to `N * N/2` which means it's `O(N²)`

Comment: offtopic: compiler authors are quite smart. I would not be surprised if this loops are replaced by some constant time expression. There was a Matt Godbolt talk where he shown compiler is able to replace loop calculating sum of arithmetic progression into single multiplication.

Comment: and [inner loop is optimized this way](https://godbolt.org/z/6b3o5nqjc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

technically the time complexity of that algorithm, or number of instructions run, is going to be in the order of:

```
Sum(N-i) for i=0 to i=N
```

since the inner loop is run N times each time running just. each iteration running 1 count less.

that sum expanded looks like this:

```
N + N - 1 + N - 2 + .... 2, 1, 0
```

which is the same as:

```
Sum (i) For i = 0 to i = N
```

this in turn can be solved to something like:

```
n(n-1)/2 ==> n^2/2 + n/2
```

And

```
O(0.5*n^2 + 0.5 n) is effectively O(n^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean asymptotic time complexity.

The inner loop will run `N-i` times and its body is O(1).

Unrolling the outer loop, the complexity is `O(N) + O(N-1).... + O(1)` which sums up to `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Your answer is shorter :).

Comment: @Rob yours is more detailed which is likely better for the OP. :)

Comment: How does O(N) + O(N-1).... + O(1) sum up to O(N^2)? One more way I was checking the output was printing the total number of times of the execution of the body.  Let's say N is 5, then it will be 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15. 15 is not 5 * 5 which is 25.

Comment: @ZoomIn It's just the formula for the sum of the arithmetic sequence + the fact that constants or lower-power terms do not matter in asymptotic case. Sum 1,2,3..N is N*(N+1)/2 - that would get 15 for N=5. See Rob's more detailed and correct answer.